# How to stop a matlab code running after certain amount of time?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I am running a function `fun()`, but I don't have access to inside it (so I can't put conditions inside it). 
The function might be slow, for some inputs. How can I terminate the program if it takes more than a certain amount of time?

Update: I am testing the function for various set of inputs. For some of them it takes more. I want to skip the ones which take too long, and move to the next input.

Comment: What is your ideal outcome once you stop the function? Do you want it to return something (like, some sort of inexact solution) or do you want to kill the entire job?

Comment: If it takes too long, just skip and move to the next input. Basically I am testing the function for various set of inputs. For some of them it takes more. I want to skip the ones which take too long.

Comment: If you can't access the function internally, that's tricky. Do you know anything about what makes the function run longer? (e.g. could you sensibly estimate this ahead of time given input sizes/values)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately MATLAB's single-threaded nature makes this more complicated than it should be. My first inkling is to use a timer, but even timer callbacks will not interrupt a busy MATLAB, as all M-Code is executed from the same thread.

I would solve this problem by calling the function from another MATLAB process, and monitoring that process. You can use the built-in SYSTEM function to call MATLAB, and use the -r command line argument to specify the name of the script to run.  The pseudocode would look something like this. This rough and untested but should give you the idea:

```
% Create Timer object
timerObj = timer();
% set timer properties, with 60 second interval
set(timerObj, 'executionMode', 'singleShot', 'StartDelay', 60, 'timerFcn', @timerCallback);
% call MATLAB. It will run in background
system( 'matlab.exe -r myscript &' );

function timerCallback(varargin)
% if the other matlab process is still running when the timer is elapsed, kill it. perhaps use another system() call to run taskkkill.exe (if on windows)
```